# jquery select only on specific level

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select elements with jquery ionly on a specific level. They have to be directly sub of `#main->table` and contain the class `x`. 
I'm trying something like that `$('#main>table .column');` But with this i also get the  second level div with the class "x" (total 3). I need just the two elements which are marked in the example with "wanted". I'm unfortunately not able to make any changes on the code...

Maybe there is something possible like `$('#main>table .column:first-child');`? Somehow that returns me 3elements as well. Best would be a possibility to consider only a specific number of levels

```
<div id=main>
  <div class=x> <!-- not wanted -->
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class=x> <!-- wanted -->
          <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <div class=x></div> <!-- not wanted -->
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table> 
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class=x></div> <!-- wanted -->                
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
$('#main>div>table>tr>td>div.x')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the class 'x' indicates a markup for level you could fileter the results based on parents length.

```
$('.x').filter(function(i,e) {
   return $(e).parents('.x').length === 1; 
})
```

This way you could easily reuse the code:

```
$.fn.filterAt = function(level, selector) {
  var ps = selector || this.selector;
  return this.filter(function(i,e) {
     return $(e).parents(ps).length === level; 
  });
};

$('.x').filterAt(1);
```

Tested using jQuery 1.7.2